For Events, where can I see each participants' final status?
I created an event with yes/no/maybe attendance options. I registered lots of "Yes" participants. Now I'm filling out the "second calls" info under "Participant Info." Where can I see lists of who -- on the second calls -- is still a yes or perhaps has changed to maybe/no?

Was "yes/no/maybe attendance options" a Custom field? Was it set to 'Searchable'?
